# node.js express-resource auto-load is not working

Tags: node.js, express, autoload, autoloader, express-resource

Has anyone managed to get the auto-load functionality of express-resource to work? I cannot get it to fire, but according to the documentation it should work:
[express-resource](https://github.com/visionmedia/express-resource)

I have tried getting it to work in both my own code and the example code in express-resource [provided here](https://github.com/visionmedia/express-resource/blob/master/examples/controllers/forum.js). I am simply adding a "console.log" statement into the forum resource's "load" function, however it seems to never be called. Code is as follows:

```
exports.load = function(id, fn){
  console.log('auto-loader');
  process.nextTick(function(){
    console.log('auto-loader in the callback');
    fn(null, { title: 'Ferrets' });
  });
};
```

Then in the "controller.js" the code is exactly as in the [example here](https://github.com/visionmedia/express-resource/blob/master/examples/controllers.js):

```
var forums = app.resource('forums', require('./controllers/forum'));
```

The reason I would like to get this working is that I want to have a blanket function that loads some data for a particular set of routes, as opposed to adding it into each route individually as middleware. E.g. I have "listings" on my site, and I want a function that retrieves the top 10 recent listings.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated I spent much of last night puzzling and concluding that the code may not work at all. I sincerely hope I'm wrong and hope to stand corrected by one of you smart cookies, because I'd really like it if I did not have to pick a different routing module!

Alternatively if you have a routing module that works with express that you know has functioning auto-load capability then please also let me know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, in case anyone else runs into this - I have found that I'm incorrect and **it does actually fire, but only sometimes!!**

**The problem is that it does not fire on all routes.** So far I have tested index, new, show, and edit. It fires for show and edit but not for index or new.

I am not sure if this is intentional or not and would love it if someone could **shed some light on why it behaves like this please**?

I have also left a comment on a very similar question on the author's github site: [load function doesn't add to req object on index route](https://github.com/visionmedia/express-resource/issues/68)

Comment: Not sure if you are still having the issue, but I came across this same issue myself, with a little frustration. After some digging, I have come to the conclusion that the authors have probably been focusing their attention on Express 4.x (and thus stopped working on express-resource). In the [Migration page](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x#approuter) (for version 3.x to 4) it pretty much says that app.router() has been dropped, and has become a full-fledged middleware.

Comment: Thanks JohnnyCoder, that makes sense.